# Mysql table name with string concate?

Tags: mysql

I want to select all those tables which tables name contain another field name

Like

```
Show Tables Like  '%' + table.table_name_prefex
```

but this give me an error below.

> ```
> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> ```
>
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '+table.table_name_prfex' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of suggests either a very clever or a very dumb schema.

You can't do this with 'SHOW' - as Haim Evgi (POST deleted) said you'll need to use the information schema.

> I want to select all those table which is begin from fields in another db

So just do a join....

```
SELECT t.table_schema
, t.table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
, otherdb.table o
WHERE t.table_name LIKE CONCAT('%',o.table_name_prefex)
AND .... /* filters to select rows from otherdb.table */
```

If your table really is called **table** then you need to enclose it in back quotes.

Comment: table name is account and field name is uid

Comment: working fine, but showing error that subquery return more than one value

Answer (score 1):

you cant do it like you want

you can do something like

```
SELECT 
 TABLE_NAME
FROM    
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES    
WHERE    
    table_schema = 'mydb' AND    
    table_name LIKE '%mypartname%';
```

Update according to remark:

```
SELECT 
     TABLE_NAME
    FROM    
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS    
    WHERE    
        table_schema = 'mydb' AND
        COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%mypartname%';
```

Comment: I want to select all those table which is begin from fields in another db.

Comment: you can write the db name in table_schema = 'mydb'

Comment: Actually I am try accomplish a task like.  there is two database. one is db1 and another is db2.   db1 contain account id and db2 contain some tables which begin with db1 account id. so I want to fetch all those table from db2 which have account id of db1